# Connect SQL Server to Python 3 with pyodbc

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=LENOVO-PCN;DATABASE=testing;')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select Sales from Store_Inf")
row = cursor.fetchone() 
if row: 
    print (row)
```

I try using python 3 with module pyodbc to connect SQL Server Express.
My codes gave a error:

> ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named
>   Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].  (2)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)')

Any idea for this?

Comment: Try `SERVER=LENOVO-PCN\\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: I tried and it gave me the error:     Error: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: Or any other settings are required but I have missed?

Comment: It sounds like you need to include `UID=` and `PWD=` for SQL Server authentication, or `Trusted_Connection=yes` for Windows authentication.

Comment: Thank you, the problem has been solved. by 'Trusted_Connection=yes'

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that worked for me using Trusted_Connection=yes

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = pyodbc.connect(
    Trusted_Connection='Yes',
    Driver='{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}',
    Server='SERVER_NAME,PORT_NUMBER',
    Database='DATABASE_NAME'
)

connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

Please note that port number is comma separated!