# pyodbc connection to MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, pyodbc

I find difficulties in the connection of pyodbc with SQL server. After reading all the questions and references, I still could not find an answer about how to deal with this error:

> Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL >Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] >[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')

My code is shown below:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}',server = 'SQLOLEDB',
database =    'K2DS1')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select*from stocks")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is the server really named `SQLOLEDB`? That looks suspicious to me.

Comment: Either the server name is wrong or you don't have permission to connect to that server, make sure that your machine is allowed to connect to server and you have sufficient permissions in server configuration

Comment: Your SQL will also fail once connected; you'd want `SELECT * FROM stocks` with spaces. The caps are optional; I choose to capitalize reserved words for clarity in reading.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to to use:

Trusted_Connection=yes

Please take a look at example that I provided at '[Connect SQL Server to Python 3 with pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47947018/30038)'